# Select two first characters and ignore duplicates

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on a MySQL database that stores lots of unique postcodes. This is how it looks like:

```
postcode_id | postcode
     ------ | ------
        1   | BA10EJ  
        2   | TR96PY 
        3   | TA64RD 
        4   | EX54NA 
        5   | EX167DT
```

I'd like to select the first couple characters and only list the unique ones, so if there are two EXs I just need to display EX once.

This is what I'm trying to get:

```
postcode
 ------
   BA  
   TR 
   TA 
   EX
```

Comment: What does your query attempt look like? How did it fail to meet your needs?

Comment: show us the desired output

Comment: Be aware that not all postcodes in the UK have two letters at the start, several have a single letter, such as B in the Birmingham area and S in the Sheffield area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select distinct substr(postcode,1,2) 
from my_table;
```

Comment: I didn't downvote it. After combining my query and your query, it worked, see my answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve my problem by using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(postcode, 2) FROM cc_postcodes
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by MySql `left(str, len)` function. This function returns the leftmost len characters from the string str, or NULL if any argument is NULL.

```
select distinct left(<mycolumn>, <no_of_chars>) as <myColumn> from <mytable>
```

To know more about [MySql Left()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`left()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) with [`SELECT DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html) to get the unique entries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(postcode,2) FROM postcodes;
```

See this working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24d6d/2/0)